# I cannot containerise my python code in a docker container

Tags: python, docker

I am learning docker. I want to practice how to see logs inside of a docker container once I run a python image.

This is the python code I want to execute:

```py
#loop.py
#loop.py
import time

while True:
    print('test')
    time.sleep(3)
```

This is the docker file:

```sh
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1


COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

CMD ["python", "loop.py"]
```

I build the image like this:

```sh
docker build -t image_test .
```

Once it is created ( I can see it doing `docker image ls`) I want to run it, I have different ways but the container is created and is terminated instantly:

`docker run <imageID>`.

I have tried too:

`docker docker run <imageID> sleep infinity`. Then I can do: `docker exec -it <containerID> bash` and I can run inside the container `python loop.py` but it automatically ends.

I modified the CMD like this as well:

`CMD ["python","-u",  "loop.py"]`

I have tried:

`docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash image_test` and I directly go to the terminal inside of the container, but if I execute the python code as before, it automatically ends, instead of run the infinite loop.

why?

Comment: By default, the in-container processes standard output isn't exposed. You might want to use the `-a` option to `docker run` to see it. You can also bind host directories to directories in the container file system, which effectively "exports" files from the container.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need bash to run a python program. You can use it to exec into a running container. But the container will be running as long as the python is connected to the stdout.

I ran these commands and they all work on my machine.

```
sudo docker run image_test
sudo docker run -d image_test
sudo docker ps
sudo docker logs -f 041
sudo docker exec -ti 041 bash
sudo docker stop 041
sudo docker rm 041
```